# Partial specialization for std::vector of all types

Tags: c++, templates

I'm not sure whether I'm going too far with templateization, but the following problem:

I have sort of a container class. This class can directly take values or it can take vectors which take values. I would like to specialize it for the second case.

How can I...

1. ...specialize the class for vectors of any type?
2. ...extract the parameter of the vector in the specialized class?

Code example:

```
// GENERAL CASE with vector of type T
template <class T>
class Container
{

        std::vector<T> container; 

        void set(T val, int idx){
            this->container[idx] = val;
        }

};

// SPECIAL CASE with vector of vectors
template <>
class Container<std::vector<all types allowed>>
{
        std::vector<The_type_of_vector> container; 

        void set(The_type_of_vector val, int idx1, int idx2){
            this->container[idx1][idx2] = val; // set element idx2 in vector idx1
        }

};
```

(Of course my Container is a bit more complicated than shown here. I could also create two different non-template versions of the container. But after thinking about it, I'm also curious how I could do it with specialization.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, all you need is the syntax.

```
// SPECIAL CASE with vector of vectors
template < typename element_type >
class Container<std::vector< element_type >>
```

You could also extract the allocator type from `vector`, if you actually want to support different allocators.

> I'm not sure whether I'm going too far with templateization

If you have a choice between writing a template or not, usually you shouldn't. Otherwise, nothing here is suspicious.

Comment: It works, but it seems pretty magic to me, since I do not define `element_type` in the original/general template definition.