# Specialise template for vector of arbitrary type

Tags: c++, templates, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a template function for converting an object to a string (this is from a library, I can't change this):

```
template <typename Q> std::wstring ToString(const Q& q) { static_assert(false, "Must specialise"); }
```

Now, I want to call it with a parameter of `std::vector<Gene>`, where `Gene` is a simple class whose details are not important. Of course, to do this, I need to specialise the template, so I do:

```
template<> std::wstring ToString(const std::vector<Gene>& q){...}
```

Suppose I have another class, `Cell`, and I want to specialise the `ToString` function for a `std::vector<Cell>`. I would have to make another explicit specialisation, with the same body as the `std::vector<Gene>` version.

The logic for converting a `std::vector` doesn't depend on the actual content type (an int, a `Gene`, a `Cell`, another `std::vector`, etc), so it would make sense to create a template specialisation that can work with any `std::vector`. But I can't figure out an easy way to do this. For now, I currently have a `VectorToString` function, and forward the call from `ToString(std::vector<Gene>>)` and `ToString(std::vector<Cell>)`, but this still requires me to implement a specialisation for each element type.

So, to the actual question: is it possible to create a single specialisation for an arbitrary `std::vector`, and how would I do this? And, as a bonus question, could this be generalised to any arbitrary collection which supports `std::begin` and `std::end`?

I have looked at this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249455/partial-specialization-for-stdvector-of-all-types) and tried declaring a specialisation like this:

```
template<typename E> std::wstring ToString<std::vector<E>>(const std::vector<E>& t){...}
```

but this fails with C2768: illegal use of explicit template arguments ("The compiler was unable to determine if a function definition was supposed to be an explicit specialization of a function template or if the function definition was supposed to be for a new function."), which makes sense since we've got the same function name and number of template parameters, and a similar signature.

For reference, I am using Visual C++ 2015 RC, and the original template function originates from the native test library.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't partially specialize functions, you are _overloading_ them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost did it correctly but in case of functions you shouldn't specialize them, you should simply overload them like so:

```
template <typename Q> std::wstring ToString(const Q& q) {
    return L"Original";
}
template<typename E> std::wstring ToString(const std::vector<E>& t) {
    return L"overload";
}
```

See http://ideone.com/G3r0Vt for an running example.

This works because when selecting the overload to call, `const std::vector<E>` is considered to be "better" than `const Q&` thus the overload is used.

When using those methods in your code you should consider [ADL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111677/what-is-argument-dependent-lookup-aka-adl-or-koenig-lookup).

Comment: I had tried something like this before, but because I thought I was specialising and not overloading, and the function is actually within a namespace, I was writing it as `template<typename E> std::wstring Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::ToString(const std::vector<E>& t)` which wasn't working, I had to wrap it in proper the proper `namespace` directives. I noticed it also worked without any namespacing, but I assume it's better practice to declare the overloads in the same namespace as the original functions.

Answer (score 2):

I have the next example for you. Try to use next:

```
template<typename E> std::string ToString(const std::vector<E>& t)
{
    std::stringstream resStr;
    for (const E& element : t)
    {
        resStr << element << " ";
    }
    return resStr.str();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.push_back(22);
    v1.push_back(33);
    std::vector<double> v2;
    v2.push_back(54.656);
    v2.push_back(44.656);
    auto strInt = ToString(v1);
    auto strDouble = ToString(v2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for vectors of base types:

```
namespace Microsoft
{
    namespace VisualStudio
    {
        namespace CppUnitTestFramework
        {
            template<typename E>
            std::wstring ToString(const std::vector<E> & t)
            {
                std::wstringstream result;
                result << L"Size: " << t.size();

                if (t.size())
                {
                    result << L", Elements: ";

                    for (const auto & element : t)
                    {
                        result << L"{ " << element << L" } ";
                    }
                }
                return result.str();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For failed tests you can clearly see the size of the vector AND the elements it contains.  For your purpose you may be able to use:

```
namespace Microsoft
{
    namespace VisualStudio
    {
        namespace CppUnitTestFramework
        {
            template<typename E>
            std::wstring ToString(const std::vector<E> & t)
            {
                return L"Size: " + std::to_wstring(t.size());
            }
        }
    }
}
```